# What does the condition #{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.renderResponse} mean?

Tags: jsf-2, el

I was checking out the code for [this template](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/showcase.xhtml) from the [OmniFaces Showcase app](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree), when I encountered the following condition used in a `p:selectOneMenu`:

```
disabled="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.renderResponse}"
```

From using the app, it seemed that the *selectOneMenu* is never disabled, so what does this code really do?

I know that `facesContext.postback` is `true` whenever the page is resultant from POST requests generated by JSF components (*commandButton/commandLink*, etc), but what would be the usual expected state of `facesContext.renderResponse` when evaluated in the View?

**UPDATE:** oops, just now I saw the comment: *They're disabled in other phases than render response, because they otherwise complain that the model value cannot be set even though there's no form*.

So, I'm guessing the condition is evaluated several times during Faces lifecycle, and the component is disabled until the last state (renderResponse) is reached, when `facesContext.renderResponse` evaluates to `true`, the whole expression evaluates to `false` and the component is then enabled. Is that about right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those `<p:selectOneMenu>` components are actually abused to have a nice `<div><ul><li>` dropdown menu with a minimum of code ;) Their values represent the current menu group and page which are by design read-only (they have no setter method). The navigation takes place by JavaScript `window.location` which is handled during change event. They are not part of any form and do not participate in any form submit.

The `disabled` attribute is theoretically not mandatory, but when a non-ajax JSF form elsewhere in the very same page is submitted synchronously, then PrimeFaces `SelectOneMenuRenderer` will still try to `decode()` it in its entirety even though it is not enclosed in any form at all. It would ultimately cause the following exception when the model value is to be updated because there's no setter for that value:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /WEB-INF/templates/showcase.xhtml @28,80 value="#{parent.children[0].viewId}": The class 'org.omnifaces.showcase.Page' does not have a writable property 'viewId'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processUpdates(Panel.java:304)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

When the `disabled` attribute evaluates `true` during [postback](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29), then the `SelectOneMenuRenderer` will skip the `decode()` during apply request values phase and thus also skip the update of model value. However, if it evaluates `true` as well during [render response phase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse%28%29), then it becomes unselectable (and thus unusable). So, it should not evaluate true during render response phase. The expression

```
disabled="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.renderResponse}"
```

achieves exactly that. All with all, it's basically kind of a workaround for the odd behavior of `SelectOneMenuRenderer` (for which I've not really investigated the underlying cause yet).

To test it yourself, pull the project, remove the `disabled` attribute and invoke a synchronous submit in for example the `<o:onloadScript>` showcase page.

Comment: Thanks, man! Very cool trick! Hmmm... So the trick is that the component is decoded only in the render response phase, right?

Comment: No, with `decode()` I basically mean processing of the form submit. The render response phase doesn't decode (apply request values), it encodes (generate HTML output). This way it's not processed during form submit at all (because it's disabled), but it appears in a normal/enabled state in the HTML output.

Comment: Right, I said "decoded" but I was thinking generating HTML. Thanks, man, I think I got it now... nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates to the [getter state](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse%28%29) for reading whether [renderResponse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) has been invoked. This method is used to instruct the [JSF lifecycle](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/) to skip subsequent phases and go straight to emitting the response (e.g. in the case of a validation failure.)

Comment: Hey, man! I think `renderResponse()` is called in every request at the end of the lifecycle, not only when skipping phases. But my doubt is more about the value of `facesContext.renderResponse` when used in the view, I'm thinking it is evaluated several times during the lifecycle...

Comment: I was wrong, I checked the usaged in Mojarra code and now I think `FacesContext.renderResponse()` is the exception, really. So, `facesContext.getRenderResponse()` evaluates true only when some phase is skipped?

Comment: It doesn't call `FacesContext#renderResponse()`, it calls `FacesContext#getRenderResponse()`.